Why does Sveltekit raise "Error loading dynamically imported module" on third-party svelte component import?
Context
I added and installed this svelte datepicker component in my small Svelt-Kit project.
The page where it should live is a CSR-only page (meaning +page.js contains export const ssr=false).
// Struture
routes  
  |___ +layout.svelte
  |___ dashboard/
      |___ +page.svelte  
      |___ create/  
          |___ +page.svelte  
          |___ +page.ts

// create/+page.ts
export const ssr = false;

// create/+page.svelte

<script lang=ts>
  import {DatePicker} from "@svelte-plugins/datepicker";

  let isOpen = false;
  let startDate = new Date();
</script>

<h3>Create</h3>

<DatePicker bind:isOpen bind:startDate>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select date" />
</DatePicker>

Issue
Heading to /dashboard/create while the development server is running redirects the browser to the parent page /dashboard after briefly showing the create page where the error is raised:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module : http://localhost:5173/@fs/[...]/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js

I would not expect an error on such a simple import.
Is there something I should be aware of regarding how to consume external svelte components?
Environment
[ "@sveltejs/kit": "2.5.5", "svelte": "4.2.12", "vite": "5.2.8"]
